# Lumia 620 totally unresponsive

Tags: charging, nokia-lumia-620, developer-preview

I have been having issues with my Lumia 620:

1. It is originally a windows 8 OS, i activated the developer's preview on it to get 8.1, after which the machine started to behave erratic by constantly going into airplane mode then shutting off .
2. I would then reset the phone to the factory settings. After which i would upgrade to the 8.1 and start over from scratch. Doing so the airplane mode issue reoccurred three times.
3. On the last time for the phone going bad, while resetting it i saw a blue screen appear with a smile face on the phone. Did my research and found out that the Lumia Software Recovery Tool was what i needed. I did the recovery and the phone was back to life, but i did not activate the developers's preview out of fear the same things happened.
4. Unfortunately the airplane mode issue did come back, after which the phone went dead and now is totally unresponsive. All attempts to restore it via the Lumia Software Recovery Tool or the Windows Phone Recovery tool has been unsuccessful. The message i am getting from both software is that the phone connected is not supported. It is no longer charging either.
5. I have tried the hard and soft resets but i am unable to do so because the down volume button is broken and will not press.

Anyone who has a solution to this problem plz i am asking for your assistance as i would really love to have this work horse of a phone back up, and more importantly, i have several important files on it i need to recover.

Comment: Sounds like faulty hardware, have you taken it to a service centre for diagnosis, at all?

Comment: Surely its an Hardware issue.. Take it to the nearest Nokia care center..